# Shear stress and force

Tags: applied-mechanics, shear, forces

I have got a cantilever beam subject to forces and moments. I found the shear force diagram  and moment diagram. I am having trouble finding the shear stress distribution and normal stress distribution. The cross section is also a T section. I know I have to use the formula QV/It to find shear stress, however I am not sure if we have to use the maximum shear force shown on shear force diagram or if V is changes with every calculations. I am only guessing we use the maximum shear force.

Comment: A diagram would certainly help.